Admin notices action failing to fire
For some reason I can't get the admin_notices action to work.
For context, I am trying to show errors when my custom post type is saved and fields fail validation. However I have stripped out most of that logic to create a minimal test case, which still doesn't work.
The one aspect that makes this a bit more complex is that my code is within a namespace and a class. This does not cause problems for the other actions and filters I call though, so no idea why admin_notices is any different. Sample code is below.
To test this I am going into any admin page and then checking the debug.log file. Needless to say I am not seeing "admin notices test" appearing there.
namespace RM;
class RM_Edit {
    public function __construct( $recipe_master, $version, $options ) {
        $this->run();
    }
    public function run(){
        add_action("admin_init", [$this,"init"]);
        add_filter("get_user_option_meta-box-order_rcpmst_recipe_comp", [$this,"metabox_order"]);
        add_action("admin_notices",[$this,"show_errors"]);
    }
    function show_errors(){
        error_log("admin notices test");
    }
....

Can anyone explain what I'm doing wrong?

Have you checked all the obvious possible issues, like WP_DEBUG is true and WP_DEBUG_LOG is either true or a path to a debug log file? Is the debug log file writable by the server process, which may be different from your user process?

posting as an answer for now as I don't have enough rep to comment and am waiting for an account merge before i can update the original post.
There is no problem with the debug logging, i have confirmed this by putting an error_log inside the run() function and this appears in debug.log.
I have since tried disabling the small number of other plugins running on my development site and have discovered the culprit. When the SiteGround Central Plugin provided by my host is disabled, the admin_notices action starts firing again. Now I just have to figure out why it is causing this issue....
...and the reason is that the Siteground Central plugin has a line of code remove_all_actions('admin_notices'); in core/Pages/Dashboard.php. Not the most helpful line of code :-( Hopefully this may save someone else the several hours it has taken me to figure this out...

and the reason is that the Siteground Central plugin has a line of code remove_all_actions('admin_notices'); in core/Pages/Dashboard.php. Not the most helpful  line of code :-( Hopefully this may save someone else the several hours it has taken me to figure this out...

It's absolutely fine to answer your own question if you happen to solve the problem before anyone else, but it would be a good idea to edit it so it stands alone as an answer rather than adding vital information in a comment below it.

Seconding @ChrisCox -- edit your answer to include the remove_all_actions('admin_notices'); information.
